# How to ask the user for permission to use location in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to use the location capability in a Windows Store App. I've already put a Bing Maps control in the XAML page.

In the code behind I'm trying to get my current location using the following code:

```
private async Task SetMyLocation()
{
var position = await this.GetCurrentPosition();
if (position != null)
this.DataContext = position;

this.myLocation = new Location(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
this.myMap.Center = this.myLocation;
}
```

And . . .

```
private async Task<Position> GetCurrentPosition()
{
  try
  {
    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
    geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    geolocator.MovementThreshold = 0;
    Geoposition location = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

    var postion = new Position
    {
      Latitude = location.Coordinate.Latitude,
      Longitude = location.Coordinate.Longitude
    };

    return postion;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    . . .
  }
```

All the code above, is executing when the user click on a button in the Application. Then when executing the GetCurrentPosition() method and triying to execute the following line of code:

```
Geoposition location = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

I got a popup message asking for user permission to use the location capabilities.

So, the question is: Is there away to ask the same thing BUT at the begining? I mean, when the App is launched?

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The popup you are seeing can't be invoked programmatically. It displays automatically when `GetGeopositionAsync` is called. Same dialog can be seen if app has defined capability for webcam. Similar dialog will appear only when photo capture method is called, you can't get "yes" or "no" for particular permission in advance.

What you can do is, invoke `SetMyLocation()` method in `OnNavigatedTo(...)` of particular page rather than in button click event.

Moreover you can set permission by code. It's fully depended upon user. User can allow/block permissions from setting charm -> permissions tab.

Comment: Hi Xyroid. You're rigth. I'm new in the Windows 8 Development. And after a while I figured out that it can't be invoke programatically as you say. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `MessageDialog` object. Something like:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Do you want to allow XXXX to use your location?");
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes"));
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No"));
var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
if(result.Label == "Yes")
    App.UseLocation = true; // Where UseLocation is a static property in your app somewhere
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Hi Nate. Thanks for your quick response. I was trying to implement the code you posted. However, I can't use any UseLocation property. Do I need to add any namespace o something like that? Or is this for a particular framework? I'm using 4.5

Comment: No, that's just a custom static property you add to your App.Xaml.cs. It is accessible from anywhere in your app.